# Using wheelnav.js how can I connect my wheel to a copy slider

Tags: javascript, wheelnav.js

I would like to correlate my wheel nav slider to my copy container. An example is shown on this link - http://wheelnavjs.softwaretailoring.net/examples.html

I've tried to figure out how to link to the selected section of my wheel but I can't figure it out. How do I set up a slider functionality that works with the wheelnav.js?

Comment: totally out of subject: all the examples are ugly

Comment: I agree but i'm working to get the actually tabs to show up. So I dont care how they look.

Comment: Hey @FlashThunder I'm so sorry for the ugly examples! :)

Answer (score 0):

After createWheel() is called, you can register callback functions to be triggered by `navigateFunction`.

```
wheel = new wheelnav('wheelDiv');
wheel.createWheel();
wheel.navItems[0].navigateFunction = function () { alert('Hello wheel!'); };
```

More info here: http://wheelnavjs.softwaretailoring.net/documentation/navItem.html